# Working principle of RC522

Tags: mfrc522

How does the antenna filtering stage work?[image: MFRC522 schematic]

Comment: I assume you've read the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf) (section 15), along with the two application notes it references ([AN1445](https://pubweb.eng.utah.edu/~mlewis/ref/NFC/AN1445.pdf) and [14443A](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach&topic=199983.0&attach=178517)). Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What are the real values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 65 pages that describes all the details
https://pubweb.eng.utah.edu/~mlewis/ref/NFC/AN1445.pdf

try a better question.